# Where are local APIC addresses in QEMU?

Tags: x86, qemu

According to Intel's document, `FEE0 0000H` to `FEE0 03F0H` is the range of local APIC. However, examining it from QEMU console, I can only find the value 0 there:

```
(qemu) x/128b 0xfee00000
fee00000: 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
fee00008: 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
fee00010: 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
fee00018: 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
fee00020: 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
fee00028: 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
fee00030: 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
fee00038: 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
fee00040: 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
fee00048: 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
fee00050: 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
fee00058: 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
fee00060: 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
fee00068: 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
fee00070: 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
fee00078: 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
```

I checked 128 bytes to see if anything different than 0. At least, `FEE0 0030H` should contain a different value since it is where APIC version is in.

Paging is disabled, so there's no virtual memory; just physical:

```
(qemu) info mem
PG disabled
```

But, `info lapic` command reports actual initial values:

```
(qemu) info lapic 
dumping local APIC state for CPU 0 

LVT0     0x00008700 active-hi level                             ExtINT (vec 0)
LVT1     0x00008400 active-hi level                             NMI   
LVTPC    0x00010000 active-hi edge  masked                      Fixed  (vec 0)
LVTERR   0x00010000 active-hi edge  masked                      Fixed  (vec 0)
LVTTHMR  0x00010000 active-hi edge  masked                      Fixed  (vec 0)
LVTT     0x00030010 active-hi edge  masked         periodic     Fixed  (vec 16)
Timer    DCR=0x2 (divide by 8) initial_count = 4096
SPIV     0x000001ff APIC enabled, focus=off, spurious vec 255
ICR  0x000c4610 physical edge assert all
ICR2     0x00000000
ESR  0x00000000
ISR  (none)
IRR  (none)
```

So, where are these values?

Comment: `x` examines virtual memory, and the local APIC's registers are mapped in the _physical_ page FEE00xxx.

Comment: This is from a very simple bootloader, with only protected mode enabled, but paging disabled. No virtual memory yet.

Comment: On top of the answer already given, you should be able to find the APIC base address on hardware/emulators (QEMU included) where the APIC built in by by loading `0x1b` into _ECX_ and using `rdmsr` instruction  . The base address would be in _EDX_ : _EAX_ .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The device is emulated. When a vCPU reads or writes to those addresses, they are handled by the emulated APIC. When GDB/the QEMU console does, it probably doesn't get routed through that emulator (emulated reads can change state). Likely, gdb/the QEMU console just gets routed to QEMU's representation of RAM, which doesn't include the APIC.

Comment: I have no idea if you are using userspace QEMU, or QEMU KVM. Both have representations of the APIC which you can likely make accessible to the console with some hackery. Might be a bit of a pain. A lazier option would be to print it from inside the guest.

Comment: I am using userspace QEMU, with standard command line to start a q35 machine and a qemu cpu. I'm not sure if the address base `0xfee00`, when paging is disabled, is applicable, since my VM only has 256 MB RAM. I tried to remap the base to an arbitrary random address with `wrmsr` instruction, to the MSR register `0x1b`. It does change the value, but when I write to the new address .e.g `0x14` is the new base, so writing to `0x14380` should change initial timer count. Yet, even after writing, I found the output remains the same from `info lapic` command.

Comment: Base address is initially 0xfee00000 regardless of paging (it's a physical address). I know modern KVM refuses to move APIC base, but I'm not sure about QEMU's full userspace behavior.

Comment: When I said the base address is `0xfee00`, I actually referred to the value in `IA32_APIC_BASE` MSR, with the value `0xfee00` at the topmost bits (position 12-31). That value is extended with to `0xfee00000` and is added to an offset for a specific APIC feature. I asked the `qemu-discuss` list and it seems reading the emulated memory has no effect on getting the correct values.

Comment: It's true that the memory reads from QEMU and GDB do not retrieve values from the local APIC. I tried writing to the default addresses, and indeed the LAPIC changed its values.

Answer (score 0):

The default is FEE0 0000H to FEE0 03F0H but it occupies the full 4KiB page. The first 16 bytes are reserved for an MSI interrupt to the core with APIC ID 0 (which is necessary if it is placed within the MSI range). MSI interrupts for the other 255 cores rest on the start of page boundaries, 1 page each, up to and including FEEF F000H. The LAPIC can be adjusted on each logical core as each logical core has an [IA32_APIC_BASE_MSR](https://www.sandpile.org/x86/msr.htm).